# Can I put all form code in one <% %> block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code in my #new form:

```
<%= form_for @phone do |p| %>
  <%= p.label :name %>
  <%= p.text_field :name %>
  <%= p.label :photo %>
  <%= p.text_field :photo %>
  <%= p.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Can I put it in one code block and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= some_code %>` print into view result of any calculations. So, several <%= %> things lead to inserting several different results into view.

If you want to use only one code block you should use concatenation:

```
<%= form_for @phone do |p| %>
<%=
  p.label(:name) +\
  p.text_field(:name) +\
  p.label(:photo) +\
  p.text_field(:photo) +\
  p.submit 
%>
```

Maybe it will lead to html escaping in view (sorry, I didn't check). Anyway, it looks pretty ugly. I recommend you to use HAML (http://haml.info/) instead of ERB, if you want to simplify your views.

Answer (score 1):

For printing in the view it is used:

```
 <%= 'This will be printed in the view' %>
```

and the code is used without the `=` . Like this:

```
<% if false%>
<%= 'This will NOT be printed' %>
<% else %>
<%= 'This will be printed' %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

code written between the delimeter '<%=' and '%>' alwayz are used to get printed on the output screen

therefore anything written like :

> `<%= is a printable/output text %>`

where as anything written like :

> `<% if a == b %>`

is just a part of logic and will never be printed

and to answer you, you cannot mix and match both of them.